# Calculating combinations with Duplicates and no Rearangements

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am wondering how to calculate the number of combinations of $n$ amount of decimal numbers, and $p$ represents amount of numbers chosen out of $n$, where rearrangements are not allowed but duplicates are allowed.

There is a formula that is like this but does not allow duplicates:

$$C(n, r) = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$$

I am looking for an equation like this but would allow duplicates.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Ball-and-urn.  When duplicates are not allowed you get a row of Pascal's triangle.  When duplicates are allowed, you get a diagonal of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Do you mean you have $n$ choices for the first number, $n$ choices for the second, etc, so you are looking at $p$-tuples chosen from your set of size $n$? If so there $n^p$ such sequences if you don't allow reorderings. But maybe I am misinterpreting what you mean.

Comment: A question on duplicates turns out to be a duplicate, nice.